# Calculate weighted mean in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like some help writing this excel formula.

I'm trying to calculate the weighted mean of term payments accordingly to their percentage of use but I'm failing on the last part of the logic expression.

```
=IF(OR(B2>0,B3>0,B4>0,B5>0),(SUMIF(B2:B5,">=1",D2:D5))/(SUM(C2:C5)),0)

%[B]    days[C]    weighted mean[D=BxC]
30        1           30
70       30          2100
0        60           0
0        90           0
total                 68.70967742
```

What I'd like to do is sum all lines in [D], if the percentage of [B] is >=1. Then I want to divide this by the sum of the days in [C] if their corresponding cell in [B] is >=1

So in this example the answer would be 68.70967742 --- [(30x1)+(70x30)]/(1+30).
What I came up with returns 11.7679558.

Thanks

Comment: This is a really well asked question, I wish they were all like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calculating weighted averages, you'll find `SUMPRODUCT` is very useful!

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$B$4,$C$1:$C$4)/SUMIF($B$1:$B$4,">0",$C$1:$C$4)
```

This returned `68.7096774` as required.